# metaData.getPrimaryKeys() returns a single row when the key is composite

Tags: sqlite, jdbc, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I have an issue with a compound primary key in JDBC using SQLite driver.

The `getPrimaryKeys()` method from a `DatabaseMetaData` object returns a single row when I have verified the key is actually a compound key consisting of two columns.

Does any one have any suggestions / alternatives how the true listing of primary keys can be retrieved?

Here is the code:

```
DatabaseMetaData meta = con.getMetaData();

ResultSet pks = meta.getPrimaryKeys(null, null, "work_on");
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = pks.getMetaData();
while(pks.next()) {
    for (int i = 1; i < rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        System.out.print(pks.getString(i) + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: work_on (s_id varchar(4), ... , primary key(s_id, p_id), ... )

Comment: It successfully retrieves both primary keys for an adjacent table. I'm not sure why it's not working for this particular table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have run into this issue:
https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/issues/107/databasemetadatagetprimarykeys-does-not

#### Workaround for the current JDBC bug

The bug in the JDBC driver is a bad regular expression matching your SQL string. The regular expression expects at least one whitespace between the `KEY` keyword and the opening parenthesis. If you write this:

```sql
create table work_on (
  s_id varchar(4), 
  p_id varchar(4), 
  x varchar(4), 
  primary key(s_id, p_id)
)
```

The primary key won't be reported correctly (because there's another bug in the fallback logic when the regular expression fails to match anything, that other bug results in only the *last* PK column to be reported). So, to work around this problem, you could carefully design your tables to always have this whitespace:

```sql
create table work_on (
  s_id varchar(4), 
  p_id varchar(4), 
  x varchar(4), 
  primary key (s_id, p_id)
  --         ^ whitespace here!
)
```

#### Workaround by not using the JDBC API

You can always run this query here yourself (which is the JDBC driver's fallback query):

```sql
pragma table_info('work_on');
```

And then collect all those rows that have the `pk` flag set to true. For instance, the following table

```sql
create table work_on (
  s_id varchar(4), 
  p_id varchar(4), 
  x varchar(4), 
  primary key(s_id, p_id)
)
```

... produces this output:

```
+----+----+----------+-------+----------+----+
| cid|name|type      |notnull|dflt_value|  pk|
+----+----+----------+-------+----------+----+
|   0|s_id|varchar(4)|      0|{null}    |   1|
|   1|p_id|varchar(4)|      0|{null}    |   2|
|   2|x   |varchar(4)|      0|{null}    |   0|
+----+----+----------+-------+----------+----+
```

Comment: I can't change the create table syntax as it was provided by a third party source. Duly acknowledged though that the issue is with the whitespace as the adjacent table mentioned had the appropriate whitespace at primary key