# metaData.getPrimaryKeys() returns four same records when the key is single

Tags: java, mysql, primary-key, mysql-connector, database-metadata

My question lies along the lines of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41526928/metadata-getprimarykeys-returns-a-single-row-when-the-key-is-composite), but a bit different. I am retrieving the primary key for a table using the following code in java:

```java
DatabaseMetaData meta = connection.getMetaData();
ResultSet rs = meta.getPrimaryKeys(null, null, "global_settings");
while (rs.next()) {
     System.out.println(rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME"));
}
```

Table *global_settings* has only one primary key column i.e. *global_setting_id*.
However, it appears that the loop runs four times and the output is:

```java
global_setting_id
global_setting_id
global_setting_id
global_setting_id
```

However, for a table with a composite key the loop works okay e.g. for Table *user_info* which has three columns which form the composite primary key i.e. *(user_id,national_id,taxation_id)*,

The loop provides the output as:

```java
user_id
national_id
taxation_id
```

I am using *mysql* and the driver is

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.18</version>
</dependency>
```

It's a bit trivial, but still a concern for the assignment I am doing. Is this a bug or an issue on my side?

Comment: So far what I understand from your code is that your `rs` contains four `results` and you are looping through it and you are displaying value of only one column (four times) `COLUMN_NAME` which I believe contains that `global_setting_id`. Please tell us what is expected result?

Comment: My expected result is that it would only display one ```global_setting_id```. Just as you have pointed out, the *rs* appears to be having four results, when it should only be one since there is only one primary key column. My view is that this function ```meta.getPrimaryKeys(null, null, "global_settings")```, has a bug that returns a resultset with four same records. Because if the primary keys were more than one column as I have explained, it returns the  columns without the buggy repetition.

Comment: Yes, but `global_settings` table contains 4 rows, and you return one primary key for each row, which in this case each row have primary key with value `global_setting_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after giving up for sometime, I accidentally stumbled accross the issue while trying out something else. The background is that I have four databases which have some tables sharing same table name, such as user_accounts, global_settings etc.
The issues I discovered were:

- I was not specifying which database the table at hand belonged to in the arguments of

```java
   getPrimaryKeys(catalog, schema, table_name)
```

The right way to do it was

```java
   getPrimaryKeys("my_database", null, "my_table")
```

The reason I was not specifying the database was because I thought the connection string i.e.

```java
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_database?..."
```

made operations very specific to the specified database.
I missed to follow what the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getPrimaryKeys(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) stated:

> catalog - a catalog name; must match the catalog name as it is stored
>   in the database; "" retrieves those without a catalog; null means that
>   the catalog name should not be used to narrow the search

- The user I was connecting with had all privileges on all the other four databases. This meant that not specifying the database I was connecting to allowed for "intrusion" to get primary key columns from tables in other databases that the user could access as well. As I have just explained, I did not know that the single database connection allowed for such kind of "intrusive" operations.

Now, you may wonder why I could not just have specified the database and stopped there. Well, the project is structured in a way that I am using the same program in order to switch connections depending on which organization database is being accessed, by using an organization id to fetch the connection string from a master database. What I missed was to fetch the organization database name as well from the connections table in the master database.

So this is the test case I performed to come to this conclusion:

1. Creating two databases *smu_teachers, smu_farmers*;
2. Creating tables *user_accounts* but with different primary key names in each database i.e.
   For *smu_teachers*

```sql
   CREATE TABLE `user_accounts` (
         `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
         `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
         `surname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
         `first_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`username`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

For *smu_farmers*

```sql
   CREATE TABLE `user_accounts` (
       `user_identity` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
       `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
       `surname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
       `first_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (`user_identity`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

3. Creating a user who has all privileges on any database starting with *smu_* i.e. user *smu_root*

```sql
   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `smu_%`.* TO `smu_root`@`%`
```

4. Creating a user who has all privileges on only one database, smu_teachers i.e. user *smu_teachers_user*

```sql
   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `smu_teachers`.* TO `smu_teachers_user`@`%`
```

5. Running the test program with user *smu_root*:

```java
@Test
public void getPrimaryKeys() throws Exception {
    DatabaseMetaData databaseMetaData = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/smu_teachers_corp?" +
                    "autoReconnect=true&allowMultiQueries=true&useSSL=false&createDatabaseIfNotExist=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true",
            "smu_root", "smu_root_password");
    try {
        databaseMetaData = connection.getMetaData();
        rs = databaseMetaData.getPrimaryKeys(null, null, "user_accounts");
        ResultSetMetaData resultSetMetaData = rs.getMetaData();
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME"));
            for (int i = 1; i <= resultSetMetaData.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Label: " + resultSetMetaData.getColumnLabel(i) + "  Value:" + rs.getString(i));
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Output:

```java
user_identity
Label: TABLE_CAT  Value:smu_farmers
Label: TABLE_SCHEM  Value:null
Label: TABLE_NAME  Value:user_accounts
Label: COLUMN_NAME  Value:user_identity
Label: KEY_SEQ  Value:1
Label: PK_NAME  Value:PRIMARY
user_id
Label: TABLE_CAT  Value:smu_teachers
Label: TABLE_SCHEM  Value:null
Label: TABLE_NAME  Value:user_accounts
Label: COLUMN_NAME  Value:user_id
Label: KEY_SEQ  Value:1
Label: PK_NAME  Value:PRIMARY
username
Label: TABLE_CAT  Value:smu_teachers
Label: TABLE_SCHEM  Value:null
Label: TABLE_NAME  Value:user_accounts
Label: COLUMN_NAME  Value:username
Label: KEY_SEQ  Value:2
Label: PK_NAME  Value:PRIMARY
```

6. Running test program with user *smu_root* but specifying the database name e.g. *smu_farmers* yields:

```java
user_identity
Label: TABLE_CAT  Value:smu_farmers
Label: TABLE_SCHEM  Value:null
Label: TABLE_NAME  Value:user_accounts
Label: COLUMN_NAME  Value:user_identity
Label: KEY_SEQ  Value:1
Label: PK_NAME  Value:PRIMARY
```

7. Running test program with user *smu_teachers* while specifying and not specifying database name yields:

```java
user_id
Label: TABLE_CAT  Value:smu_teachers
Label: TABLE_SCHEM  Value:null
Label: TABLE_NAME  Value:user_accounts
Label: COLUMN_NAME  Value:user_id
Label: KEY_SEQ  Value:1
Label: PK_NAME  Value:PRIMARY
username
Label: TABLE_CAT  Value:smu_teachers
Label: TABLE_SCHEM  Value:null
Label: TABLE_NAME  Value:user_accounts
Label: COLUMN_NAME  Value:username
Label: KEY_SEQ  Value:2
Label: PK_NAME  Value:PRIMARY
```

In case anyone else faces a similar issue, this can assist them to easily tell what they are doing wrong.